# Cloud firestore for ecommerce app.

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

With all the promise of cloud firestore, I would like to know if it’s appropriate for an ecommerce app. A kind of social marketplace application. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore) will be a perfect fit for an e-commerce app.
Main features of firestore that help in e-commerce:

**1. Real-time sync**

All the changes that made in the app will be reflected instantly on all the devices. So updating details of a product will be very efficient.

**2. Complete offline support**

One of the important features of an e-commerce app is, it should be functional offline, and firestore provides us this feature without the need of any extra coding

**3. NoSQL DB and querying**

Managing DB and writing and reading from it, is very easy, and also firestore supports chain filters and combine filtering and sorting on a property in a single query.

**4. Cloud function support**

This is a cool feature and it will be very useful for sending notification etc according to user behaviors.

**5. Android, IOS and Web support**

Firestore have support in android, ios and web.

You can reduce development time drastically if you use firestore.

These are all the advantages that I can come up with. Now there are some **small** **disadvantages**, which is **searching through firestore** and the query limitation on inequality.

It is specified in there [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search): "**Cloud Firestore doesn't support native indexing or search for text fields in documents**.". But they also mentioned a solution to use **third-party search service like Algolia**.

I will not say go for firestore blindly. Carefully compare it with other alternatives too.

Comment: Yeah and remember the query limitation on inequality.

Comment: Yeah , i  added that into the answer.

Comment: What are the alternatives you talked about? Offline support is the main issue for me. How do you achieve the with say MySQL?

Comment: I had worked with Firestore and it works really good in offline. If you want to use MySQL db, then you have to cache the data in the device, so you can show them when the device is offline. It will take a lot of time to develop that very efficiently. So its better to go with firestore.

Comment: No, I don't know anyone in this field.

Answer (score 0):

> AFAIK it doesn't suit you right now.

I have tried to create a simple Questionary App (MCQ Quiz of different subject). A question have an array of Tags(Subject). If I like to show the question related to mathematics and physics it doesn't provide me. I have to call service for each subject and remove the common one.

It doesn't support database in function

It doesn't have OR operation (Can't use multiple where )

And a lot more basic function.

According to no SQL ranking it comes to 7 number where as mongoDB is number 1.