# Can I use Cloud Firestore for E-commerce Website? And how?

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, e-commerce

I have a client asking for an e-commerce website and considering I'm a frontend Vue.js developer and never coded backend ever, I was thinking of using Cloud Firestore for the backend. Can somebody kindly drop down a brief roadmap I will have to follow in order to build an e-commerce site with firestore with user authentication and admin controls? 
.
.
.
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Firestore can be used as the No SQL database for your e-commerce app, in fact, is a perfect solution for that purpose given all the functionalities it offers, as described in this [community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50288116/12857703), however, it cannot be used as your backend per say since it is, as mentioned before, a database.

You could, however, use other Firebase (The broader product platform that included Firestore) products that could integrate with Firestore as described on this [article](https://bloggingkarma.com/firebase-for-e-commerce/), like Cloud functions for example.

If you choose to use Cloud Functions you can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating) for more details on how to implement authentication using it.

Now, for the roadmap, I don't believe that this is on the scope of what the StackOverflow community is suppose to provide you, since we can never antecipate functionalities you would want to add to your app or your client's requirements, so you should consider bulding one by your own. That being said, there are many examples online that you could use to build it. I have not found any for vue.js but I did found this one for [react](https://dev.to/andersjr1984/react-and-firebase-ecommerce-site-walkthrough-2h5b) and this one for [angular](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-create-an-app-with-firebase-and-angular-part-2-79063adebab9), which could be useful never the less.

Hope this helps you.